# Reset autoincremental value for @id Objectbox

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

Is there any way to reset the autoincremental counter for a field annotated with `@id`? We are trying to test our repositories and it would be really helpful in order to have a database in an empty state.

**Test set up**

We have an utility class that provides a singleton instance of the database connection. For each test class, we obtain that instance.

Once obtained, before executing each test, we set the initial DB state (delete all previous DB data and execute the inserts for the initial data).

We're following the same pattern that we've used with MySQL in order to avoid the DB creation on each test but maybe that's not the best way to test objectbox repositories.

I've seen that there is a method that allows to delete all files from the DB but it requires to have all the DB connections closed.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your test set up? If you start from scratch, it always starts at ID 1.

Comment: @MarkusJunginger I've added some info about our test set up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way for ObjectBox unit tests is actually to close the store and delete files. There's no concept of a "connection" to a database.

Here is a JUnit base class taking care of everything:

https://docs.objectbox.io/android-local-unit-tests#base-class-for-tests